# How to compile python code from user, for an e-learning game?

Tags: python

I am thinking about building an e-learning game that takes the user's python code and compile it to see if the user wrote the right code or not.

I have no idea from where to start, I would just appreciate it if someone would point me out to the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a built-in function called [compile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `py_compile` module for that. First, dump your code in a text file, for example:

```
with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
  f.writelines('print("Hello World")')
```

Then, you can do the following to compile 'test.py':

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('test.py')
```

If `test.py` has no error, `py_compile.compile` will succeed and generate a `.pyc` file called `test.pyc`. However, if `test.py` has some error, `py_compile.compile` will raise an exception, which you could handle and return to your user. For example, if you `test.py` has a missing `(` braket, `py_compile.compile` generated the following error for me:

```
>>> py_compile.compile('test.py')
  File "hello_world.py", line 1
    print "Hello World")
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Right off the mark

Comment: Wow, that's a good answer :)